# jquery mobile 'tap' is working but ' doubletap' is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, click, mouseevent, double-click

I am using ipad to check the function , the problem is doubletap does not work. And I have disable doubletap zoom and touchmove already, How to fix the problem ? thanks

```
$('#page').bind('tap', function(){
        alert('test');
        }); 

$('#page').bind('doubletap', function(){
        alert('test');
        });


addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, true);

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: There's a lot out there on this: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+double+tap What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks, as I saw some plugin for double tap  ,jquery mobile do not provide a doubletap event?

Comment: That double tap plugin seems have flaws though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery mobile events instead of jquery mobile . It works

Comment: A link is sometimes very useful, https://github.com/benmajor/jQuery-Mobile-Events